# Are there any issues with having an ASP.NET web site running with DLL's with mixed runtime versions

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

Are there any issues with having an ASP.NET web site running with DLL's with mixed runtime versions?

I'm checking a web application that has been handed over to us, and the majority of the references have got `Runtime Version v4.0.30319`, but I've spotted a few with `Runtime Version v2.0.50727`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should not be any issues since .NET is backwards-compatible. However, it's recommended to match the version of your DLLs with the version of .NET you are targeting, so maybe have a look to see if any of the DLLs with v2.0.50727 Runtime Versions have newer releases.

References:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/47a587hk%28v=vs.71%29.aspx
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee819091.aspx